# How can i sort date column in yadcf datatable?

Tags: sorting, date, datatable, yadcf

I have a yadcf datatable which include date column.
I can filter by date but i can not sort by date. Some of my codes is below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([
        {column_number : 0, filter_type: "range_date", date_format: "dd.mm.yyyy", filter_default_label: ['from', 'to']},
        {column_number : 1, filter_type: "date", date_format: "dd.mm.yyyy", filter_default_label: ['select date']},
        {column_number : 2, filter_type: "auto_complete"},
        {column_number : 7, column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text", filter_default_label: "Select tag"}]);


});
</script>
```

please help me.
thanks

Comment: for the record, here is the answer for this question: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/256#issuecomment-158449911

Answer (score 0):

Daniel already pointed this out, but please see https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/